# Is it possible for VSCode Insider Edition to be launched by Anaconda Navigator? Regular VSCode works OK

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda, launch

This is on Windows 10 using Anaconda Navigator 1.9.12 64 bit install.

Answer (score 0):

10 months later and it's still cropping up as a problem. If I find a work-around I'll come back here to report.